# Filtering, transposing and concatenating with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying something i've never done before and i'm in need of some help.

Basically, i need to filter sections of a pandas dataframe, transpose each filtered section and then concatenate every resulting section together.

Here's a representation of my dataframe:

df:

```
id | text_field  | text_value
1    Date          2021-06-23
1    Hour          10:50
2    Position      City
2    Position      Countryside
3    Date          2021-06-22
3    Hour          10:45
```

I can then use some filtering method to isolate parts of my data:

```
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: True)
test = df.query(' id == 1 ')
test = test[["text_field","text_value"]]
test_t = test.set_index("text_field").T
```

test_t:

```
text_field | Date        | Hour
text_value | 2021-06-23  | 10:50
```

If repeat the process looking for row with id == 3 and then concatenate the result with test_t, i'll have the following:

```
   text_field | Date        | Hour
   text_value | 2021-06-23  | 10:50
   text_value | 2021-06-22  | 10:45
```

I'm aware that performing this with rows where id == 2 will give me other columns and that's alright too, it's what a i want as well.

What i can't figure out is how to do this for every "id" in my dataframe. I wasn't able to create a function or for loop that works. Can somebody help me?

To summarize:

1 -  I need to separate my dataframe in sections according with values from the "id" column

2 - After that i need to remove the "id" column and transpose the result

3 - I need to concatenate every resulting dataframe into one big dataframe

Comment: Does `text_field` for id 2 really have `Position` listed multiple times like in the example?

Comment: Yes, it does. This is just a representation, the actual dataframe has thousands of lines e the text values are often repeated.

Comment: Do you care if the results for id 2 where your columns would be duplicated have a list of items with one position column?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand how that would be, but i guess it'd be ok. In this case, nonrepeated values are much more common and more important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(
    index='id', columns='text_field', values='text_value', aggfunc='first')
```

Output:

```
text_field        Date   Hour Position
id                                    
1           2021-06-23  10:50      NaN
2                  NaN    NaN     City
3           2021-06-22  10:45      NaN
```

It's not exactly clear how you want to deal with repeating values though, would be great to have some description of that (`id=2` would make a good example)

---

**Update:** If you want to ignore the `id`s and simply concatenate all the values:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('text_field')['text_value'].apply(list).to_dict())
```

Output:

```
         Date   Hour     Position
0  2021-06-23  10:50         City
1  2021-06-22  10:45  Countryside
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I really like your solution, but, correct if i'm wrong, the aggfunc 'first" returns only the first ocurrence by id, right? 
I actually need all of the data for each id. I'm testing with this solution because it helped me already, though.

Comment: @Luan Yes, that's correct, `first` will keep the first value for each `id`. It is possible to have a different `aggfunc` to have all values aggregated into a list or something like that, depending on what you want to achieve

Comment: If you just want to concatenate all values by `text_field` disregarding the `id`, see my update section for a simple way to achieve that (assuming equal number of records for each `text_field`)